# Quickly browse localized app store descriptions in other languages and/or countries?

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

As I am writing and translating localized app store descriptions for my app, I thought it would be handy to read other same-category apps' localized descriptions. However this has become more complicated than I had hoped (e.g., don't really want to change my Mac's language setting on top of my iTunes store country preference). Plus I have had limited success doing this on with OS X and iOS.

Can someone suggest a quick and easy way to look at app store descriptions in another language? I am sure I am missing something obvious here, for example currently I am poking around App Annie to see if it has archived localized descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a solution. You can use the urls that Apple provides and read the app description from there:

Head over to http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/ and you will see that there you can select a country.

For example, searching for "Twitter" in iOS apps and US you get (after removing the trailing url garbage):

[`https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8`](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8)

Now just change the country code. E.g., German and Italian:

[`https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8`](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8)
[`https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8`](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8)

Comment: The links in the answer are broken.

Comment: @Flimm Yes, it is an old answer to an old question. Can you correct them? I notice that some of them are still working.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to modify URL and view it in browser.

If you open an app using URL:
itunes.apple.com/app/APP_NAME/ID

(for example: https://itunes.apple.com/app/zuko-monsters/id545619234?mt=8)
you can just add country code after first part:

itunes.apple.com/de/app/APP_NAME/ID
itunes.apple.com/us/app/APP_NAME/ID

(for example: https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/zuko-monsters/id545619234?mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

The way for this is https://fnd.io/

Just enter the locale/country you would like to see and you can find any app.

It has saved me hours!